# Querying and storing array in sql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

So I recently started working with PHP CodeIgniter and SQL queries, I want to fetch all the sellers who have the selected items a user is searching for, so only show sellers who have `[item1,item2...]`

Method 1 ( Doesn't work because sql can't store arrays)
Storing an array of items within seller's table

```
seller1.allItems = [1,2,3,4,5]
seller2.allItems = [3,4,5,6]
```

So if user searches for item 3,4 ... it should show `seller1` AND `seller2`
(Doesn't work because SQL can't store arrays)

Method 2 .. create new table

```
INSERT INTO `selleritems` (`id`, `seller_id`, `item_id`, `value`) VALUES
    (1, seller1, 1, 22),
    (2, seller1, 2, 22),
    (3, seller1, 3, 22),
    (4, seller1, 4, 22),
    (5, seller1, 5, 22),
    (6, seller2, 6, 22),
    (7, seller2, 7, 22),
    (8, seller2, 4, 22),
    (9, seller2, 5, 22)
```

so this is the new table I created for each items the seller has with their value.

Now if the user searches for  item 3,4 ... it should show `seller1` AND `seller2`

and if searches item2,3.. only show `seller 1`

Query part (this is where I need help)

```php
$this->db->from('selleritems');
        $this->db->where_in('item_id', array(item2,item3) );
        $this->db->where('value >', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

so this query gives me both sellers, how can I make sure it only returns the sellers who has all items from the passed array items?

Edit: I tried

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM selleritems WHERE item_id IN ( 1 ) AND value > 0 group by seller_id"; 
    returns (seller1)

$sql = "SELECT * FROM selleritems WHERE item_id IN ( 4 ) AND value > 0 group by seller_id"; 
    returns (seller1,seller2)

$sql = "SELECT * FROM selleritems WHERE item_id IN ( 1 , 4 ) AND value > 0 group by seller_id"; 
    returns (seller1,seller2)
BUT it should only return (seller1) because seller 1 has both items while seller2 only has item4 not item1
```

Comment: Please that query 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM selleritems WHERE item_id IN( item2, item3) AND value =>0 group by seller_id";
$this->db->query($sql);

Comment: I am confused by the question -, 'how can i make sure it only returns the sellers who has all items' -'if the user searches for item 3,4 ... it should show seller1 AND seller2'  - seller2 does not have item3 so why would seller2 be in your result set?

Comment: Can you add your desired output - I am unclear whether you want only the rows which has the stipulated items, all the rows for the seller or only the sellerid.

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar thanks i tried that and **query1= tiem_id IN ( 1 ) ... returns (1,3,6,7) query2= tiem_id IN ( 2 ) ... returns (2,4,6,8) .... so Query3=tiem_id IN ( 1 , 2) returns (1,2,3,4,6,7,8)   BUT it should return (6) **. as only seller6 has both items

Comment: @P.Salmon please check my last comment

Comment: ' BUT it should return (6) . as only seller6 has both items'-  there is no seller6 in your sample data..

Comment: @P.Salmon please check my last comment, i have added new data with Mahesh's query example to make it easier

Comment: Please share share data with result what you want ??

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar updated the question, i want result of sellers who has both items

Comment: @P.Salmon do you get it now?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to match the `seller_id` row count with the item count :

```php
$items = array(item2, item3); // item_ids
$item_count = count($items);
$this->db->select('*, count(id) count_ids');
$this->db->from('selleritems');
$this->db->where_in('item_id', $items);
$this->db->where('value >', 0);
$this->db->group_by('seller_id');
$this->db->having('count_ids', $item_count);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: this doesn't work, and if array has 1 items it returns 0 object.. so totally doesn't work

Comment: looks like it returns everything else except what i want, so its returns all sellers who have even 1 item, but it doesn't return who has both

Comment: same result, returns all sellers except who has both items

Comment: can you help? haven't found any solution yet other than doing multiple queries